# How can I get **kwargs from url by urls.py setting?

Tags: python, django

I am building a RESTful API by Django.

One API have 6 params and they all have default value. Basically I want user pass 0 to 6 pair of param and the view function use default to rest. And params are unordered

For example：

```
/month/6/date/12/    # for June 12
/year/2012/month/6/  # for June, 2012 
/date/12/year/2012/  # for 12 in every month in 2012
```

I hope this can work, but it can't

```
# in urls.py
url(r'(?:([a-zA-Z]+)/(\d+)/)*','kwargs.views.aview')

# in views.py
def aview(request,*args):
    # even in args are keys and odd are values 
    return HttpResponse(args)
```

In this moment, I only have one ugly solution in my mind:

```
   # in urls.py
url(r'([\w/]*)','kwargs.views.aview')

# in views.py
def aview(request,args):
    args = args.split('/')
    # even in args are keys and odd are values 
    return HttpResponse(args)
```

Is there any elegance way to do that？

Comment: check this post: http://cramer.io/2009/07/15/dynamic-keyword-arguments-in-django-urls/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first regular expression, you have indeed only two groups, which gets overwritten all the time. I would suggest a not so ugly solution, by checking the correctness of the url in a regular expression, but in only one whole group, and split and convert the single argument into a dict:

```
url(r'((?:(?:[a-zA-Z]+)/(?:\d+)/)*)','kwargs.views.aview')

def aview(request,args):
    args = dict(zip(*[iter(args.split('/'))]*2))
    return HttpResponse(args)
```

edit: with correct reg-exp.

Comment: It still not able to work. It also just fetch last pair of param.